# Google Geocoder language localization... is it broken?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

I'm looking to reverse `geocode Lat/Lng's` to addresses in multiplue languages, after reviewing the `Google Geocoder API` it should on paper always be possible. But it seems to fail badly.

e.g.

`Lat/Lngs` for London UK requested in English return the expected results:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.5073509,-0.12775829999998223&sensor=false&language=en

`Lat/Lngs` for Lisbon Portugal requested in English return the results in Portugese with Lisboa for Lisbon despite being requested in English:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=38.7436266,-9.1602037&sensor=false&language=en

The same is true the other way around for London requested in Portuguese (change the "`en`" on the end of the first link to `pt`, `pt-PT` or `pt-BR`) it always comes back with the English for Country and City.

Is this broken? Can anyone suggest a better service that works in multiple languages?

Thanks

Comment: Strange behaviour yes, I tried some tests with FR / EN languages and the values are updated sometimes but not on every item of the result.
Not able to help you more as I cannot suggest a better service for multiple languaues

Comment: You can try [Openstreetmap's Nominatim Reverse Geocoding / Address lookup](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup)

Answer (score 1):

There are good reasons behind the choice of language in all the above cases, see more details (and examples) at [How can I get Chinese words using Google API with JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520686/how-can-i-get-chinese-words-using-google-api-with-json/37867402#37867402)