# Localization for Google Geocoding API results

Tags: google-maps, localization, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

i'm using Google Geocoding API to make reverse geocode of coordinates.
i'm using the following link with some hundreds city in the world (the limit for the queries is 2500 per day):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=43.7667624,11.2175238&key=MY_GOOGLE_APY_KEY
```

I would get only english content as output and i add `&language=en-EN` according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?csw=1#Localization).

But it doesn't work. I'm from Italy and it shows me results in italian, instead of english. Maybe the Google geocoder uses the browser's preferred language (or IP address?).

Is it possible to force it to use english only?

Comment: Have you tried just to add &language=EN ?

Comment: Sure, it doesn't work. Isn't it weird?

Answer (score 3):

You do get results in English, but street-level addresses will still use names in the local language, with the country name in your desired language. This only happens to the first 2 results in your example, all others are entirely in English:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=43.7667624,11.2175238&language=en

1. `premise`: Via dell'Olivuzzo, 146, 50143 Firenze, Italy
2. `street_address`: Via Duccio di Buoninsegna, 19, 50143 Firenze, Italy
3. `locality`: Florence, Italy
4. `postal_code`: 50143 Florence, Italy
5. ...

There are good reasons behind the choice of language in all the above cases, see more details (and examples) at [How can I get Chinese words using Google API with JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520686/how-can-i-get-chinese-words-using-google-api-with-json/37867402#37867402)