# Google Places API details language not working

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am working on a bilingual project and started to use Google Places API Webservices. I started using the [Place Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) which works great.

I can do this query in both `fr` and `en` and will get different description results:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=`<insert_key_here>`&types=geocode&language=`<insert_language_here>`&input=144

English result:

```
  "description": "14458 Gouin Boulevard West, QC, Canada",
  "id": "33dcffeeb88b48fa5c1d0ec4e6e54469d05f5d1e",
  "place_id": "ChIJk0pAHBM7yUwRt0WIxWRe1ic",
```

French result:

```
  "description": "14458 Boulevard Gouin Ouest, QC, Canada",
  "id": "33dcffeeb88b48fa5c1d0ec4e6e54469d05f5d1e",
  "place_id": "ChIJk0pAHBM7yUwRt0WIxWRe1ic",
```

The ids are exactly the same but the text is localized which is the expected result. Now when I try to get the same result using the [Place Details API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details), the language parameter doesn't seem to have any impact. I know that the documentation mentions `results should be returned, if possible.` but given I know it is possible, is this behavior by design or some sort of bug?

Here is an example of an english details query using the previous example place_id which returns the result in french:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=`<insert_key_here>`&placeid=ChIJk0pAHBM7yUwRt0WIxWRe1ic&language=en

```
    "long_name": "Boulevard Gouin Ouest",
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520686/how-can-i-get-chinese-words-using-google-api-with-json/37867402#37867402 ─ while maybe not exactly a duplicate, Places Details is pretty much like Geocoding API in terms of address formatting and language selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While doing more researches, it looks like this is an old/known problem with the Google Places Details API. I did open a new issues [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9496) but given this has been reported multiple times there is no way to know when/if they will fix this.

An old 2012 thread can also be found with similar problems [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3987).

Some workaround have been suggested in a previous [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567757/inconsistent-language-in-google-place-details-api) but for my given use case it did not do any good.

For the time being, the only real option I could think of would be to use Google Translate API which is [unfortunately not free](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing). Given the detail's response, one could parse every field and try to translate them before rebuilding an address. This would of course be a risky/fragile given that one cannot predict how the machine translation will work in all scenarios. Having Google support localization in their Places API would be much simpler option and make a lot of users happy.